# Feature detection of buggy IndexedDB implementations?

Tags: javascript, ios, internet-explorer, safari, indexeddb

I have an IndexedDB-based app. Previously it was easy to do feature detection on IndexedDB - just see if `window.indexedDB` is defined or not. However, two things have changed recently:

1. Safari was released with very broken IndexedDB support
2. I rewrote part of my app to use features (compound indexes and multientry indexes) that IE does not support

So now I need some more fine-grained feature detection to show a reasonable error message to Safari and IE users.

I can imagine testing for IE's missing features wouldn't be too difficult, since at least the problems are documented. But for Safari, there are multiple bugs and I don't know how well it's documented anywhere. Heck, I don't even own any Apple devices that I can run Safari on. And what if some other browser in the future releases a buggy IndexedDB implementation?

Has anyone thought about or solved these problems before? Seems to me like there should be some standard IndexedDB feature detection library, but I can't find anything (Modernizr's IndexedDB stuff doesn't seem sufficient).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IE you can check: `IDBKeyRange.only([1])`, this throws an Exception `DataError` on IE.

For Safari I did some useragent sniffing because I couldn't find a way to check, (I could have created a dummyDb and check with the inserts if it would remove my other values) but that would be asynchronous making everything a bit more difficult)..

Comment: That's a great idea for IE! Can you share how you're detecting Safari?

Comment: I believe it was something like this, but it is definitely not future proof:

var matches = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone);.*OS (\d+)_(\d+)/);
    if (matches && matches.length == 4) {
        var iOSVersion = parseFloat(matches[2] + "." + matches[3]);
        if (iOSVersion >= 8 {
         // broken indexedDb
        }